# Images getting cropped with FlatList

Tags: android, react-native

The images are getting croped how can i prevent that from happening? Notice that only appears half of the image. This is a Android device. Idont know if this happens in IOS too. But a fix for android would be great

[image]

My FlatList component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';

const shows_first = [
    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'Suits',
        image: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/2432.jpg'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        name: 'Modern Family',
        image: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/628.jpg'
    },


]

const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
        <Image style={{ width: 120, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
    )
}

const List = () => {

    return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 110 }}>
            <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: 5 }}></View>}
                renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem(item)}
                data={shows_first}
            ></FlatList>
        </View>
    )
}

export default List;
```

Comment: What is your expected result ? Didn't get with "overflowing the header"

Comment: I edit the post. seems like the images are getting croped for some reason in my flatlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a resize mode to chose how you want to display your image. 
If you are sure that all your images are going to be posters better give a height and width that suits the image.
Check the code below

```
const renderItem = (item) => {
  return (
      <Image style={{ width: 80, height: 120 ,resizeMode: 'center'}} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to style your image to fit as per aspect ration so to do that you will have to add resizeMode='contain'

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/cranky-scones

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const DATA = [
  {
        key: 1,
        name: 'Suits',
        image: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/2432.jpg'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        name: 'Modern Family',
        image: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/628.jpg'
    }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={({ item }) => 
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Image style={{ width: 120, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} resizeMode='contain'/>
          </View>
        }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```